# What is the effect of pressing the back button on the app's process in android?

Tags: android

I know that pressing the back button destroys the activity even if the activity is the main activity of my app . But then why do i see my app in the list of open apps . Does android keeps the app's process alive even after destroying the main activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the back button destroys the activity and stops the entire application if this was the startactivity or the last running activity.

The application is still shown in the list of open apps but this has nothing to with the *state* of the app. This list could better be described as a list of running and recently closed apps. Maybe to start a recently closed app faster again.

Comment: I think the list shows apps which have at least one process running . I created a started service and then pressed the back button . When i checked my app manager ,it shows my app in the running state having one process and one service running .

Comment: When your app uses services and the service is running it's clear that it is shown in the task manager. You first need to call stopService to stop that service.

Comment: But maybe you are right . Even after i deleted the service from my app ,i can see the app in the list . So maybe it shows running as well as recently closed apps

Answer (score 0):

if you look on android api website for activity lifecycle, you'll notice a stop/restart cycle, so an activity is not necessarily destroyed once it is exited and may linger in memory in the stopped state.

https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: No you are completely wrong . Please read the documentation carefully. The activity will go to stop state if you are pressing the home button . The back button always destroys the activity unless you override onBackButtonPressed()